# Charasteristic Method for PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

Hi i'm struggling a little with solutions of PDE. I have to solve the following

> $$\begin{cases}\partial_xu +y^2\partial_yu = 2yu+y^2\\ u(0,y)=y \end{cases}$$

I want to use the method of characteristics so I write the system
$$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = 1\\\dot{y} = y^2\\\dot{z} = 2yz+y^2\end{cases}$$
with $z(t)=u(x(t),y(t))$ and if this is a homogeneous PDE I can solve the first two row and I obtain that the characteristics curve are
$$x +\frac{1}{y}=c$$
And the general solution of the homogeneous PDE is $$u(x,y) = F\bigg(x+\frac{1}{y}\bigg)$$
since this PDE isn't homogeneous I have to solve the last row and here comes the problems. I look at $\dot{z} = 2yz+y^2$ and I think its a ODE and I can solve it with the formula but then how can I use the characteristics to solve the entire equation, how can I find the general solution and how can I use the condition $u(0,y)=y^2$? I'm very confused on that part, thank you very much for the help.

Edit: 1) $u(x,y)=F\bigg(x+\frac{1}{y}\bigg)$ does not solve the homogeneous PDE but $\partial_xu +y^2\partial_yu =0$

Comment: How do you justify the general solution? What is the second constant expression? $z=u(x,y)$ is not constant along the characteristics.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't quite get what you're asking me, I know that $z=u(x,y)$ is not constant otherwise the PDE will be homogeneous I think. My problem is that when PDE are homogeneous, I think I get what I should do to  evaluate the solution, but when is not homogeneous I'm walking in the dark...

Comment: @LutzLehmann as a justification of the general solution for homogeneous PDE I think using the chain rule is enough or am I wrong?

Comment: You should be able to solve the differential equation between $y$ and $z$. This gives an integration constant $c_2$. The idea is then to set $c_2=F(c_1)$ and derive an equation for $u$ from this.

Comment: @Turquoise Tilt. Probably you didn't put your solution $u(x,y) = F\bigg(x+\frac{1}{y}\bigg)$ into the PDE in order to check it. You would see that it doesn't agree in general. Takes account of the judicious comment from Lutz Lehmann.

Comment: @JJacquelin by mistake I meant homogeneous the equation that presented only the partial derivatives and not the function u, so the $F$ that I found in my head solves not only the first two row of characteristics system but also the homogeneous PDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\partial_xu +y^2\partial_yu = 2yu+y^2$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{du}{2yu+y^2}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{y^2}$
$$x+\frac{1}{y}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{du}{2yu+y^2}\quad\implies\quad \frac{du}{dy}=\frac{2u}{y}+1$ :
$$\frac{u+y}{y^2}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicite equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\frac{u+y}{y^2}=F\left(x+\frac{1}{y} \right)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the boundary condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-y+y^2F\left(x+\frac{1}{y} \right)}$$
Condition :

$u(0,y)=y=-y+y^2F\left(0+\frac{1}{y} \right)\quad\implies\quad F\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)=\frac{2}{y}$

With $X=\frac{1}{y}$ the function $F(X)$ is determined :
$$F(X)=2X$$
We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $X=x+\frac{1}{y}$.

$u(x,y)=-y+2y^2\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)$
$$u(x,y)=2y^2x+y$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but why can we put $c_2=F(c_1)$ sorry for the silly questions but I'm quite confused, after that all the calculations are clear to me

Comment: This question is not silly, it belongs to the hard core facts in the method of characteristic curves. The handwavy argument is that the solution is a surface of dimension 2 that you fill with characteristic curves of dimension 1, so that the family of curves has a continuous index of dimension 1. So if you get 2 constants, there has to exist a functional relationship between them. In the best case one is a function of the other. @TurquoiseTilt

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you, do you have any suggestion for books about characteristics method? Also, if for example the PDE was in three variable so the solution is $u=u(x,y,z)$ the constant that I'm searching are $c_i, i=1,2,3$ and each one could be a function of the other two or is a little bit too complicated to use this reasoning? Thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt : Then you still get one functional relation, in examples usually that one constant is a function of the two others. Notice that the boundary or initial condition is now also over a 2D surface.

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you very much, I ask you this question too, do you have any suggestion for books on this specific subject? With your answers I'm starting to get a little bit of understanding but I'd like to look into this matter further

Answer (score 1):

Since the PDE is linear and inhomogeneous, its general solution can be written as $u = v+w$, where $v$ is the solution to the homogeneous PDE,
$$
v_x+y^2v_y=2yv, \tag{1}
$$
and $w$ is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation. Let's first solve $(1)$. The characteristic equations are
$$
dx=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{dv}{2y}. \tag{2}
$$
The solution to $dx=\frac{dy}{y^2}$ is
$$
x+\frac{1}{y}=C_1, \tag{3}
$$
whereas the solution to $\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{dv}{2y}$ is
$$
v=C_2y^2, \tag{4}
$$
hence the general solution to $(1)$ is
$$
v(x,y)=y^2F\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right), \tag{5}
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

To find a particular solution $w$ to the inhomogeneous equation, let's make the ansatz $w=w(y)$. With this ansatz, $w_x=0$ and the PDE becomes a linear inhomogeneous ODE:
$$
y^2w'(y)=2yw(y)+y^2. \tag{6}
$$
One can easily check that $w(y)=-y$ is a particular solution to $(6)$. Combining it with $v(x,y)$, Eq. $(5)$, we conclude that the general solution to the inhomogeneous PDE is given by
$$
u(x,y)=-y+y^2F\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right). \tag{7}
$$
To determine $F$, we use the condition $u(0,y)=y$:
$$
-y+y^2F\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)=y \implies F\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)=\frac{2}{y}
\implies F(t)=2t, \tag{8}
$$
hence, finally,
$$
u(x,y)=-y+2y^2\left(x+\frac{1}{y}\right)=2xy^2+y. \tag{9}
$$

Comment: I agree with your solution.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. But someone downvoted without saying why. Thay is why the score is still $0$ instead of being $1$.

Comment: Your solution is as valid as mine. It is always a good idea to first solve the homogeneous equation and add a particular solution when it is possible to do it easily.

Comment: @Gonçalo I think as the answer above you put $c_2=F(c_1)$ why we can do this? Also this method could be used in general but rely on the fact that we can find a particular solution of the PDE otherwise we could not use this method right?